# What verb can I use to mean "cause financial costs"?

Tags: word-request, formal-language

I'm trying to describe (very succinctly) the financial impact of a given scenario. If it happens, it will cost money.

What is the right verb to describe this? My first thought is to ***cause** financial costs*, but it doesn't sound entirely right.

Comment: You're right. It might CAUSE financial **distress/harm/damage** but it will **entail/involve/necessitate** (high/serious) costs.

Comment: Cause financial *loss*?

Comment: You could consider inflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very commonly-used word for that situation is ***[incur](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incur)***:

> **incur** *transitive verb*
>   : to become liable or subject to : bring down upon oneself   *• incur expenses*
>   *<sub>definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incur)</sub>*

Note how the dictionary's own example uses "expenses".  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about simply ***increase*** financial costs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not too far from what I am looking for, but I feel it implies that there _are_ some costs already, whereas in the case I am describing the costs would "appear" (i.e., there were no costs otherwise).

Comment: In everyday usage, that would still count as an increase. `Incur` as suggested in the alternative answer is probably not strong enough for this usage.